# SQL First and Last Occurrences - Group By forcing me to group everything in select

Tags: google-bigquery

Table1

```
EmployeeID | StartDateTimestamp | CohortID | CohortName
---------- | ------------------ | -------- | ----------
1          | 20080101 01:30:00  | 1        | Peanut
1          | 20090204 01:01:00  | 2        | Apple
2          | 20190107 05:52:14  | 1        | Peanut
3          | 20190311 02:35:26  | 2        | Apple
```

Employee

```
EmployeeID | HireStartName | StartDateTimestamp2
---------- | ------------- | -------------------
1          | HiredStart    | 20080501 01:30:00
1          | DeferredStart | 20090604 01:01:00
2          | HiredStart    | 20190115 05:52:14
3          | HiredStart    | 20190330 02:35:26
```

Learning on the go. My query below will list out all the EmployeeID's and not just the first Cohort ID and last Cohort ID. Group by forces me to group StartDateTimestamp2 with employeeid and it still lists all employee ID's, and does not look like intended result below.

Ideally, the (first occurrences) result should be:

```
CohortID | StartDateTimestamp2
-------- | -------------------
1        | 20080501 01:30:00
2        | 20190115 05:52:14
```

My Query Below

```
SELECT firsttable.Cohortid,
       employeetable.StartDateTimestamp2
FROM   Table1 firsttable
INNER JOIN Employee employeetable ON employeetable.employeeid = firsttable.employeeid
```

The actual question:
Use first instance of CohortName to determine the start date of each cohort

Result:

```
Cohort ID | StartDateTimesstamp2
```

Comment: 3 questions is too much. You should just ask one. Also, you would rather provide your data as tabular text so it is easier to consume for SO folks willing to help.

Comment: Also, are you using mysql, or bigquery? These are two different databases, which different features. Please tag only the relevant one.

Comment: There's no `GROUP BY` in your query. Where are you trying to use a `GROUP BY`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this dataset, simple aggregation should do it:

```
select cohortID, min(StartDateTimestamp) StartDateTimestamp2
from table1
group by cohortID
```

Or, possibly:

```
select 
    t.cohortid, 
    min(e.startdatetimestamp2) startdatetimestamp2 
from table1 t
inner join employee e on e.employeeid = t.employeeid
group by t.cohort_id
```

Comment: Hi sorry I was editing with your suggestions. I need the StartDateTimestamp2 in the 2nd Employee table, joined by EmployeeID

Comment: So

```SELECT Cohortid,

   Employee.StartDateTimestamp2
FROM   Table1
INNER JOIN Employee ON Employee.employeeid = Table1.employeeid```

Comment: @RoastedCarrot: the problem with your sample data is that both tables have the same date values, so that's quite ambiguous what you really want. You should probably edit your question to make the sample data clearer about that.

Comment: @RoastedCarrot: I updated my answer with anoter query. Does this better fits your need?

Comment: I tried your answer and I get the error that t.cohortid is Select list expression references t.cohortid is neither grouped nor aggregated.

Comment: @RoastedCarrot: my bad. Fixed.